# How to access caller model from behavior in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need caller model in my behavior to find and save data. How can I do something like this.

```
class MyBehavior extends Behavior {
    public function func() {
        $entities = $this->find()->all();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table instance a behavior is attached to, is being passed to the constructor, and assigned to the `$_table` property.

```
public function func() {
    $entities = $this->_table->find()->all();
}
```

See also **[API > Cake\ORM\Behaviour::$_table](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.html#$_table)**

Comment: Thank you @ndm. Do you know what caused this warning: <<<Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to App\Model\Behavior\ToolsBehavior::__construct() must be an instance of App\Model\Behavior\Table, instance of App\Model\Table\GendersTable given, called in ...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\BehaviorRegistry.php on line 108 and defined [APP/Model\Behavior\ToolsBehavior.php, line 9]>>>. **LINE 9**: `public function __construct(Table $table, array $config) {`

Comment: The Cookbook example is missing the proper `use` statement to import the table class - answer updated. @anghazighermezi

Comment: Updated, as I got fooled by the docs :) The table property already exists. @anghazighermezi